# Wamp server error while configuring SSL/TLS

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, wamp, wampserver

I am getting error when I use below line:

```
 Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

I have made change this from:

```
#Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

What is the problem? Why does wampp not run with SSL after un-comment the line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to enable ssl in wamp server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065281/how-to-enable-ssl-in-wamp-server)

Answer (score 1):

Download and install Win32OpenSSL-1_0_1h.exe or the 64bit verion from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html