# How to enable https (localhost) url in WAMP server (v2.5)?

Tags: php, apache, ssl, https, wamp

I am using wamp server and running php project in localhost. I would like to test my project using "https" based url.

I tried with "https://localhost/myproject/" and it redirecting me to "This webpage is not available" page.

I have enabled "php_openssl" and "ssl" module into apache config. But still unable to access https based url.

Comment: You can't simply replace `http://` with `https://` - HTTPS is a **secure** connection, and thus requires an [SSL certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL_certificate).

Comment: @GoBusto I am not trying to replace url. I want to enable the ssl for wamp server to test my project.

Comment: You can see also this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TH6evGKgy20

Answer (score 47):

You have to set up your WAMP first with key and a certificate:

1. Download openssl choose the appropriate version according to your Operating system from [here](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).
2. Install it, than run the cmd and get where you've installed it:
    `cd 'C:\OpenSSL-Win**'` be sure be in the appropriate folder
3. run these commands :

   - `C:\OpenSSL-Win..\bin>openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.key 2048`
   - `C:\OpenSSL-Win..\bin>openssl rsa -in private.key -out private.key`
   - `C:\OpenSSL-Win..\bin>openssl req -new -x509 -sha1 -key private.key -out certificate.crt -days 36500 -config C:\OpenSSL-Win..\bin\openssl.cfg`

   You will be asked to enter a pass phrase for *private.key*, *Country Name* and so on.
4. Once you are done, the files will be generated: `private.key` and `certificate.crt`, create a folder, name it **key** in this path `C:\wamp...bin\apache\apache2.*.**\conf` .
5. Open this file `httpd.conf`. You'll find it in `C:\wamp...bin\apache\apache2.*.**\conf` uncomment these lines by removing `#` at the beginning of the line, than save the file.

   ```
   LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
   LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
   Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
   ```
6. Open `httpd-ssl.conf` file  you'll find it also in `C:\wamp...bin\apache\apache2.*.**\conf\extra` and change the default value by these lines, pay attention to the path, I ve created a folder `ssl` inside `C:/wamp../bin/apache/apache2.*.**/logs/`

   ```
   <VirtualHost _default_:443>
   #   General setup for the virtual host
   DocumentRoot "C:/wamp../www"
   ServerName localhost:443
   ServerAdmin admin@example.com
   ErrorLog "C:/wamp../bin/apache/apache2.*.**/logs/ssl/error.log"
   TransferLog "C:/wamp../bin/apache/apache2.*.**/logs/ssl/access.log"
   ....
   CustomLog "C:/wamp../bin/apache/apache2.*.**/logs/ssl/ssl_request.log" \
   ....
   SSLCertificateFile "C:/wamp../bin/apache/apache2.*.**/conf/key/certificate.crt"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/wamp../bin/apache/apache2.*.**/conf/key/private.key"
   ```

   once done save your file.
7. I copied ssleay32.dll & libeay32.dll from `C:\wamp..\bin\php\php7.0.10` folder to `c:\windows\system32`.
8. finaly check the configuration get in `cd C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin` and run this command `httpd -t` if everything is okay you will get .

   ```
   C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\bin>httpd -t
   Syntax OK
   ```
9. https://localhost/ will work for you :)

Comment: +2, Excellent Tutorial, just two things, A) in step 1, version 1.0.2 seems to be working for 64bit wamp. B) I needed to restart wamp after step 8. Thank you. Note: [if its 64bit wamp, Can't load ssl mod error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40051366/7735285)

Comment: This is correct and should be marked as is. @appsntech, could you please make the honors? =)

Comment: This not work for Virtual host and custom localhost domain such as: `https://project.dev`

Comment: @AliHesari Don't use the .dev domain for local domains, as Google bought the top level domain and dns servers will mess things up for you. I suggest using .local -cheers

Comment: To anyone having problems with generating the certificate.crt file, try wrapping the path in quotes like so: `openssl req -new -x509 -sha1 -key private.key -out certificate.crt -days 36500 -config "C:\OpenSSL-Win..\bin\openssl.cfg"`

Comment: not working  i use like this way  c:\........ bin>openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.key 2048
genrsa: Can't open "private.key" for writing, Permission denied

Comment: if you are running `GitBash` and get stuck when running `openssl genrsa ...` on `Windows`, change to `winpty openssl genrsa ...`

Comment: @azdoud I have followed your step, It's open with HTTPS but with red color *not secure* and the certificate is not valid on the chrome browser. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

By default, you can't use https protocol for your wamp connections.
What you need to do is to set up a self-signed certificate on wamp.

Follow [this tutorial](http://www.lmhproductions.com/31/how-to-setup-ssl-on-wamp/) for more information.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14366683)

Comment: That's right, I will make it when I have some free time

Comment: Having just arrived here from a cursory Google search, could I check if you're able to update this answer to include the essential pars of the external (linked) tutorial? Also, given the time since posting, it *might* be worth updating the chosen tutorial in case of outdated practices (though I've not yet read that tutorial, so I'm unsure if it's necessary as yet).

Comment: this is very old tutorial and not valid for current releases.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I've moved my answer to the original topic - [How to enable SSL in WAMP Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065281/how-to-enable-ssl-in-wamp-server/)