# Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server

Tags: windows, apache, configuration, wamp

I'm trying to set SSL to my localhost server with WAMP. (https://localhost)

I followed this Youtube course:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TH6evGKgy20

But finally, I got this error by running "httpd -t" command in Apache folder:

```
D:\Programs\wamp3\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\bin> httpd -t
httpd: Syntax error on line 173 of D:/Programs/wamp3/bin/apache/apache2.4.17/conf/h
ttpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: The operating system cannot
run %1.
```

What's the problem?

Comment: This post has some solutions to this error.   http://serverfault.com/questions/477706/apache-ssl-on-64-bit-windows-not-a-valid-win32-application

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem was OpenSSL version.

I was installed Win 32 version before, but I should install Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.2j Light ([from here](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)). Also, "Copy DLLs to Windows System directory" option must be checked in the installation wizard.

After installing it, everything worked correctly!

Comment: I just tried this - and the latest version (1.1.0) of OpenSSL from the link above doesn't work.  1.0.2 does thankfully!!

Comment: Even today, the version 1.1. doesn't work  for Apache2.4 on Win10 64bit.

Comment: Confirming: 1.0.2q works on Apache 2.4 on Win10 64-bit.

Comment: Apparently, the "experimental" tag applies to the entire 1.1.1 branch, not just the MSI as I interpreted that without RTFM.

Comment: Only wasted 2 hours of my day before I discovered this thread!  Thank you so much!! Version v1.0.2r works with Windows 10 and Apache 2.4

Comment: Nothing changed - v1.1.0L is not marked "experimental", but didn't work for me either (Apache 2.4 on Win10 64-bit). "Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.2t Light" did the job.

Comment: Please where can i get this 1.0.2 installer

Comment: @TinySkillz Seems that they've removed v1.0.2 from the mentioned link. Found this on google: https://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/windows/dependencies/openssl/v1.0.2j/

Answer (score 1):

I'd a problem with running mod_ssl on simply oldest Apache/2.4.41 version on Windows Server 2016, witch perfect works on Windows 10 Pro. Fix solution for WS2016 consist in updating to the new Apache/2.4.43 or copying mod_ssl.so from Apache/2.4.43 to Apache/2.4.41 modules.

> Note: that Update httpd 2.4.41 with OpenSSL 1.1.1.e! Make sure the run time variable OPENSSL_CONF [is set](https://serverfault.com/questions/876916/openssl-not-enabled-on-apache-2-4-windows-10). Be sure you installed latest Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015-2019