# Wamp not working properly after enable ssl module

Tags: php, apache, ssl

I have using WampServer Version 3.0.6 32bit with window 10 (32bit) in VMware Workstation 12 Player.

```
Apache 2.4.23 -
PHP 5.6.25 - 
MySQL 5.7.14
```

and also using

```
Win32OpenSSL-1_1_0f
```

I try to run localhost with https.

I followed this [link](http://www.mytechblog.in/install-ssl-windows-localhost-wamp-http-ssl-https/).

private.key & certificate.crt created successfully and I have setup properly in httpd-ssl.conf file as per instruction.

But I enable below module with remove # Apache

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

After then restart WampServer with services that time WampServer not start properly and WampServer icon convert red to orange only but not convert in green.

but I disable below module then start wamp server its working fine properly.

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

I try to run httpd -t its given
"Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: The operating system cannot run %1"

I enable also php extension.

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Please Help how to configure localhost with https.

Comment: Go check the error logs.

Comment: "httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 184 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: The operating system cannot run %1." This  error.

Comment: @AbidHussain: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40017498/cannot-load-modules-mod-ssl-so-into-server

Comment: wait are you trying to load a .so onto windows????? should be .dll