# Google chrome does not support localhost https url in WAMP server

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, wamp

I enabled HTTPS on localhost in WAMP server by using this tutorial: [How to enable https (localhost) url in WAMP server (v2.5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047078/how-to-enable-https-localhost-url-in-wamp-server-v2-5)

Or Video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TH6evGKgy20

This worked fine for `https://localhost/project-path`.

I created a virtual Host with custom domain name `neygin.dev`. When I use `https://neygin.dev` my Chrome browser show following error (Version 63.0.3239.84):

**Can this problem be solved?**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf/26252312#26252312 Specifically the bit about  _This connection is untrusted_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome prefixes local development sites with https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47748864/chrome-prefixes-local-development-sites-with-https)

Comment: @JoshLee This question is not duplicate.