# Chrome prefixes local development sites with https

Tags: google-chrome, https

Installed some updates on Ubuntu and now Chrome is prefixing all of my local development sites with https. I haven't got any certificates installed so Apache is refusing to connect and I'm getting this error message:

```
This site can’t be reached
xyz.dev refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I'm using Chrome 63.0.3239.84 on Ubuntu 16.04

The sites work in Firefox 57.0.1 so its a Chrome specific thing.

How do I switch this off in Chrome?

Comment: You can’t switch it off. Google has bought the `.dev` TLD, so now they think they can do what they think is best with it. https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/ Switch to another extension for local development, or install at least a self-signed certificate in your Apache.

Comment: oh great.... Thank you for the quick reply though! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can’t switch it off. Google has bought the .dev TLD, so now they think they can do what they think is best with it.

https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts has more info on the whole issue.

Switch to another extension for local development (I usually prefer `.local` - hope they don’t get their grubby little fingers on that one at some point, too, LOL), or install at least a self-signed certificate in your Apache.

Comment: this is helpful info. I am still having security trouble using a `.local` ending though