# Dev environment refuses to connec using Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Not sure if it's the best place to ask, but this is the issue:

I'm working in ubuntu, using `nginx` + `php` + `mongodb` to power my local work and recently, when trying to acess `mywebsite.dev` using Chrome, it gives me a `This site can’t be reached - mywebsite.dev refused to connect` .

There were no updates with work packages and it works fine using Firefox, I'm assuming it's some issue with chrome himself.

I have disabled dns type extensions that could cause this and tried some different Chrome settings as well, but no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome prefixes local development sites with https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47748864/chrome-prefixes-local-development-sites-with-https)

Comment: @JoshLee Yeah, you're probably right. Thanks!