# How to use Google Chrome and Virtual Hosts after version update, still works in Quantum Firefox

Tags: php, apache, google-chrome, xampp

How do you use Google Chrome for virtual hosts in (XAMPP) after the latest version?

I tried searching around on other threads but none seems to fix this current issue with virtual hosts. 
So, I'm using Xampp. I've set up my virtual hosts.

\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/DevMarketer/public/"
    ServerName devmarketer.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

and C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts\

```
127.0.0.1 devmarketer.dev
```

This means.. on Firefox Quantum when I type in the address bar: **devmarketer.dev** . 
My browser should get re-directed to D:/xampp/htdocs/DevMarketer/public/.. 
which works perfectly on Mozilla Firefox.

However, it did work on Google Chrome too until I updated the version, and now I only receive this message.

```
This site can’t be reached
devmarketer.dev refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome prefixes local development sites with https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47748864/chrome-prefixes-local-development-sites-with-https)

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by changing your ServerName from `devmarketer.dev` to:

`devmarketer.test` or `devmarketer.local` (choose another extension for local development)

and then restart your Apache server, this happens in all new versions of Google Chrome because Google has bought the .dev TLD