# facebook Connect in local development without HTTPS?

Tags: facebook, https, localhost, wampserver

I am using Facebook Connect in my PHP application but facebook wants a secure URL but i don't have it on localhost on my wampserver.
is there a solution to work with Facebook Connect without https in development?

Comment: No there is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use https on localhost. There are tools for this, for example: https://github.com/davewasmer/devcert

For PHP, check out this thread: [How to enable https (localhost) url in WAMP server (v2.5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047078/how-to-enable-https-localhost-url-in-wamp-server-v2-5)