# Why Getting Permission denied on HTTPS on WAMP Server?

Tags: https, wamp, lan

I setup HTTPS on wamp server using link below:

[How to enable https (localhost) url in WAMP server (v2.5)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047078/how-to-enable-https-localhost-url-in-wamp-server-v2-5)

and this is my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    **Require all granted**
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

but when I browse it from another machine, I get the following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.
Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1c PHP/7.3.12 Server at 192.168.1.141
Port 443
```

How can I resolve this??

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error and in fact searching, I found the blow configuration as a solution (**httpd.conf**):

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```