# Wampserver 3 with SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to install SSL certificate on Wamp. I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.mytechblog.in/install-ssl-windows-localhost-wamp-http-ssl-https/) here, everything was done without errors, just fine. But when I try to access https://localhost nothing happens. The page shows an error saying it's an insecure connection. If I continue anyway, then I get the https on the address but marked with red alert.

Also, I'm trying to access only the localhost, but usually I'm working with multiple webpages via virtual host, so instead of accessing `localhost` I would access something like `mysite.me or` `https://mysite.me`

Note: I'm using Windows 10.

---

Edited: As requested in the comments, I'm adding my httpd-ssl.conf file

```
Listen 443

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4
SSLProxyCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!MD5:!RC4
SSLHonorCipherOrder on 
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv3
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache        "shmcb:E:/Install/wamp64/logs/ssl_scache(512000)"
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "E:/Install/wamp64/www"
    ServerName localhost:443
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ErrorLog "E:/Install/wamp64/logs/ssl_error.log"
    TransferLog "E:/Install/wamp64/logs/ssl_access.log"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "E:/Install/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/certificate.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "E:/Install/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/private.key"

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory "E:\Install\wamp64\www">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    CustomLog "E:/Install/wamp64/logs/ssl_request.log" \
        "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236351/installation-ssl-in-wamp-server-error-in-httpd-ssl-conf/26252312#26252312

Comment: @RiggsFolly That one gave me the same result. It only solved an error I had with the `.dll`, but after that, the same problem appear when I try to access `https://...`

Comment: Did you really try and make `localhost` an secure site? Maybe you had better show your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file for starters

Comment: And then you `httpd-ssl.conf`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I didn't made any changes in the `httpd-vhosts.conf` since it was created automatically via the wamp service. But I did changed the `httpd-ssl.conf` according to the link you gave, to the other answer on the SO site, because it has more details.

Comment: Well chop the comments out of it and lets have a look

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ok. I just edited my question and added the `httd-ssl.conf` file

Comment: I assume you uncommented this line `Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf`

Comment: Did you try an `httpd -t` to test the config files

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes and yes. Have uncommented the line and the console print `Syntax Ok` for the command line. I've been trying everything on the past 2 days and can't make it work. =/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable SSL in WAMP Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065281/how-to-enable-ssl-in-wamp-server)