# How can I run laravel on https on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, api, lumen

I am new to Laravel and I now I am working on Fb connection with laravel. I am faced with a problem. When I try to login with facebook from localhost I receive an error in CMD (Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)) and in browser I receive this error:

[image: Fb error]

Do you know? Is there any setup that I can make? 
I am using WAMP and I want to run a command or install a composer package that serves me my localwebsite on https://localhost:port

Comment: why you port 8080? it's no secure port

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [laragon](https://laragon.org/) for your local development

or you can create a virtual host

**wamp**:
[how to create virtual host](https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/) ,
[how to enable https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065281/how-to-enable-ssl-in-wamp-server)

**xampp**:
[how to create the virtual host](https://ultimatefosters.com/hosting/setup-a-virtual-host-in-windows-with-xampp-server/) , [how to enable https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801425/enabling-ssl-with-xampp)

**or if you installed Apache, MySQL,PHP separately on Linux (LAMP)**
[how to create the virtual host](https://blog.e-zest.com/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-host-configuration-on-lamp-environment/) , [how to enable https](https://serverfault.com/questions/744960/configuring-ssl-with-virtual-hosts-under-apache-and-centos)

Answer (score 0):

If it's only to test some Facebook login (meaning you don't need to use HTTPS locally all the time) you can also use Ngrok https://ngrok.com/
It will create a public URL (which can be HTTPS) to your local server.